# How to compare DD/MM dates in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery, comparison

I'm trying to compare two dates without the year, only the day and the month (DD/MM) when for example ***30/04 < 02/05***.

I want to be able to say wether a date is previous or not to another date based only on the day and the month without paying attention to the year.

I tried to use `FORMAT_DATE("%d/%m", DATE("2021-04-30")) <= FORMAT_DATE("%d/%m", DATE("2021-05-02"))` but unfortunatly it returned `FALSE`.

I cannot find something that could resolve this properly.

What would you do ?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare values as *ordered* strings, then the ordering needs to make sense.

Put the month first:

```
FORMAT_DATE('%m/%d', DATE('2021-04-30')) <= FORMAT_DATE('%m/%d', DATE('2021-05-02'))
```